# WPF playing MediaElement pause does not stop video

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

programming C# WPF media player application.
I have placed a canvas, on that canvas i placed a mediaelement and button, when clicking the button i want to video to pause, so i made the following function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ mediaElement1.Pause(); }
```

When I debug, it enters the function but does not pause the video.

Why is that ?

Thanks

MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement Canvas.Left="72" Canvas.Top="33" Height="168" Name="mediaElement1"    Width="271" Source="C:\Users\ilans\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SampleWPFVideoApp\SampleWPFVideoApp\SampleWPFVideoApp\Wildlife.wmv" UnloadedBehavior="Manual">
            </MediaElement>
```

Button:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="45" Width="45" Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="150" Panel.ZIndex="1" Click="button1_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
            <Image Source="Images\play.png"/>
        </Button>
```

Comment: you mean that in debug mode, using a breakpoint, the video does not stop? If yes, does it stop without a breakpoint?

Comment: i mean the video does not stop when i press the button, no matter in debug mode or not.. the .Pause() does not affect it

Answer (score 5):

Try with `LoadedBehavior = Manual`

From [MediaElement msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.loadedbehavior.aspx):

> LoadedBehavior must be set to Manual in order to interactively control
>   media with the Play, Pause, and Stop methods.

Comment: Your code works on my computer if I add LoadedBehavior = Manual. Strange if it doesn't work for you.

anyway the code you posted only _Un_loadedBehavior is set to Manual, not LoadedBehavior